# What does "Using" in Serilog JSON configuration do?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

What does actually `Using` do in Serilog JSON configuration (e.g. in AppSettings.json file in .Net Core environment)?

Let us take this configuration for example:

```json
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ], <=======***HERE***=========
  "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "RollingFile",
      "Args": {
        "pathFormat": "logs\\log-{Date}.txt",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "My Application"
  }
}
```

In the example above we used `File` sink **WITHOUT** adding it to `Using` attribute. However, everything seems to be working ok.

So I cannot understand exactly why we basically need this `Using`. Could someone explain it to me please?

Comment: In the app.config equivalent package Serilog.Settings.AppSettings, it appears to be for utilizing sinks from other assemblies. Here's [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings#using-sink-extensions-from-additional-assemblies). Perhaps it serves same purpose for Serilog.Settings.Configuration? Though I don't understand how it's able to use the File sink without it....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation for [`Serilog.Settings.Configuration`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration):

> (This package implements a convention using `DependencyContext` to find any package with `Serilog` anywhere in the name and pulls configuration methods from it, so the `Using` example above is redundant.)

This means that it's used to define which packages are used for locating Serilog sinks, but it's redundant when using the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` package.

---

**More Information**

I've had a look at the Serilog source code in order to be able to provide more information on exactly what `Using` does and why it might be needed in the first place. I hope the following explanation is helpful.

Consider the following code-based setup:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

In this example, `Console` is an extension method for `LoggerSinkConfiguration` (and so it takes, as its first parameter, an instance of `LoggerSinkConfiguration`). When using this code-based approach, the code will only compile if this extension method can be found within a referenced assembly.

Next, consider the following approach, which uses the `IConfiguration`-based approach:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(someConfiguration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

```json
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console"], // Redundant.
        "WriteTo": ["Console"]
    }
}
```

In this example, the compilation process has no knowledge of what the JSON string value `"Console"` refers to and so there's a need for a process that can go from the string `"Console"` to the `Console()` extension method mentioned above. In order to do that, Serilog needs to first *find* the extension method *at runtime* (which, in this example, lives in the `Serilog.Sinks.Console` assembly).

This finding process is done using reflection, which does a bit of assembly scanning to [find `public static` methods that take as their first parameter a `LoggerSinkConfiguration`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/master/src/Serilog/Settings/KeyValuePairs/CallableConfigurationMethodFinder.cs#L40). The `Using` directive you've asked about in your question is a [mechanism for helping determine exactly which assemblies should be scanned](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/master/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/ConfigurationReader.cs#L272) when looking for these extension methods.

As the documentation states, the `IConfiguration`-based approach uses `DependencyContext` in order to [automatically scan assemblies that have `Serilog` in their name](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/master/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/ConfigurationReader.cs#L297). Because `Serilog.Sinks.Console` *does* have `Serilog` in its name, there's no need to add this to the `Using` directive. You also have the option to [provide your own `DependencyContext` instance](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/master/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.cs#L47) when using this approach and so you might then need to be explicit about which assemblies to scan when looking for sinks.